# Links just by hovering a mouse

Tags: click, hover

I basically want to create a website where no clicking is neccessary.

So when you place your mouse over any link it goes to that link without needing to be clicked.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am currently using html and javascript.

Comment: Well...basically all you need for that would be `onmouseenter` events and `document.location.href` to move to another page. Be aware though that it will definitely confuse your users and won't work without JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2):

Although this is possible, I would **strongly** advice against it. Your visitors will expect links to work the way they normally do. This principle is called [affordance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance), and breaking these expectations will cause confusion and frustration.

**Edit**:

Having said that, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uAaUE/1/

Please try it out and experience for yourself how this clashes with your mental model of a "link".

Answer (score 0):

Start here for inspiration! http://dontclick.it/

Comment: This is a good example of an alternative form of navigating information. It works well, mainly because it navigates naturally within the same page and the "links" don't look like HTML links.